# understanding this recursive function in a BST tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm having a hard time understanding this code for the ranking of nodes by size. Rank returns the size of all the nodes less than the key.

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html

how is the result returned for rank(key, x.left)???

code:

```
 public int rank(Key key) {
        return rank(key, root);
    } 

    // Number of keys in the subtree less than key.
    private int rank(Key key, Node x) {
        if (x == null) return 0; 
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key); 
        if      (cmp < 0) return rank(key, x.left); 
        else if (cmp > 0) return 1 + size(x.left) + rank(key, x.right); 
        else              return size(x.left); 
    }


 // is the symbol table empty?
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    // return number of key-value pairs in BST
    public int size() {
        return size(root);
    }

// return number of key-value pairs in BST rooted at x
private int size(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0;
    else return x.N;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that rank does not return an entry (a node value) but rather a value that represents the comparison between given Key and that of the candidate Node's left subtree (the left-most value for a node in a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)).

The value it returns stems from an implementation of the standard [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html): negative integer if first element is lesser than second, positive if it is greater, 0 if they are equal.

In this particular case, the exact number returned indicates the distance (difference) between both keys being compared, which might be useful for the code using the comparison result--usually, sort algorithms.